# Python: setting configuration parameters

Tags: function, python

What's your preferred way of processing configuration parameters?

For example:

```
test(this=7)
```

could be processed by:

```
def test(**kw):
  this = kw.pop('this', 1)
  that = kw.pop('that', 2)
```

or

```
def test(**kw):
  if 'this' in kw:
      this = kw['this']
  else:
      this = 1
  if 'that' in kw:
      that = kw['that']
  else:
      that = 2
```

Is there a better (more pythonic) way?

Comment: what's wrong with `def test(this=1, that=2):` ?

Comment: @JBernardo - nothing, although it can get unwieldy if there are lots of parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the possible parameters and defaults are fixed, the Pythonic way is to write:

```
def test(this=1, that=2):
    ...
```

If the parameter list is dynamic, your approach with *kwds.pop()* has a nice advantage of letting you verify that all the arguments were used (detecting misspelled parameter names for example).  It is instructive to look at a fragment from the code generated by `collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=True)`.  Notice the final check to make sure all arguments were consumed from kwds:

```
    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new Point object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('x', 'y'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % kwds.keys())
        return result
```

Comment: The final check is a nice touch

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to loop through the key/value pair's like so:

```
def test(**kw):
    for k, v in kw.items():
        if k == 'this':
            something = v
        # etc...
```

Comment: How do you set default values?

Comment: With **kw alone you wouldn't.  If I needed default values for parameters I would do `test(a=1, b=2, **kwargs)`.